# How to disable button in Angular if list / array is not empty?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, css-selectors, angular-services

In my component I'm getting data from my service:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._sharedService.
    getReceiptItem().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).
    subscribe(products => this.receiptItems = products);
}
```

So how can I disable a button if my array `this.receiptItems` has any items?

I've tried something like this:

```
 <div class="top-left">
    <button [disabled]="receiptItems.count>0" type="button" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
 </div>
```

But obliviously that is not a solution..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) in javascript

```
   <button [disabled]="receiptItems.length>0" type="button" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
```

Comment: do this  [disabled]="receiptItems?.length

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Update your code with following:

```
<div class="top-left">
    <button [disabled]="receiptItems && receiptItems.length>0" type="button" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `length`

> component.ts

```
receiptItems:Array<any>;
ngOnInit() {
  this._sharedService.
    getReceiptItem().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).
    subscribe(products => this.receiptItems = products);
}
```

> component.html

```
<div class="top-left">
    <button [disabled]="receiptItems.length > 0" type="button" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button *ngIf="receiptItems!=undefined" [disabled]="receiptItems.length>0" type="button" [routerLink]="['/administration']"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></button>
```